# Unable to use map data to save to DB

Tags: java

> In my application I am getting Status object from DB and setting it in
>   User object and finally saving User to database as:

```
Status status = statusRepository.findOne(UserServiceConstants.STATUS_OPEN);
user.setStatus(status);
userRepository.save(user);
```

> This is fine . But since status codes are limited I want status codes
>   to store in a map and use whereever I want. For this I created below
>   class.

```
@Configuration
public class StatusConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    StatusRepository statusRepository;

    Map<Integer, Status> statusMap = new HashMap<Integer, Status>();    


    public Map<Integer, Status> getStatusMap() {
        return statusMap;
    }


    public void setStatusMap(Map<Integer, Status> statusMap) {
        this.statusMap = statusMap;
    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        List<Status> statusList = new ArrayList<Status>();

        statusList = statusRepository.findAll();
        statusList.forEach(status -> {
            statusMap.put(status.getStatusId(), status);
        });
    }
}
```

> I autowired this in classes wherever i needed status
>       So instead of using

```
Status status = statusRepository.findOne(UserServiceConstants.STATUS_OPEN);
user.setStatus(status);
userRepository.save(user);
```

> I am using :

```
Status status = statusConfiguration.getStatusMap().get(UserServiceConstants.STATUS_OPEN);
user.setStatus(status);
userRepository.save(user);
```

> But i am getting error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.rawtrade.model.Status; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.rawtrade.model.Status
```

> Could someone help me please. I am using this in Spring boot and I am
>   new to this.

Comment: Do you load Status and User with different EntityManagers? It seems Status is not attached in the Context of the EntityManager where User is attached to.

Comment: I am not using any EntityManager just getting the status into map using Spring data jpa and using map to fetch status code. U can see the StatusConfiguration class.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring and its Repository-API but I'm pretty sure they internally use EntityManager and "detached entity passed to persist" is thrown when one side of a relation is not attached to the EntityManager and the other side is persisted. That's all I can say. Maybe you should have a look at the Repository documentation to find out how to share the same EntityManager/Transaction between multiple repositories.